# vault: How to reduce the lease duration of ssh otp?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am use the following comand to generate one time password:

```
$ vault write ssh/creds/otp_key_role ip=172.31.47.83
Key                Value
---                -----
lease_id           ssh/creds/otp_key_role/TqKAoY2kWLN058cRIzJab5qY
lease_duration     768h
lease_renewable    false
ip                 172.31.47.83
key                ec90e030-f126-ae76-c989-177f33401536
key_type           otp
port               22
username           test-user
```

the `lease_duration` of otp is 768h, I want to reduce the lease_duration to 1h, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to reduce the max lease duration for dynamic secrets. It needs to be run inside the server where vault is running and vault CLI is installed

```
vault secrets tune -max-lease-ttl=60m /pathtosecret
```

The "pathtosecret" should be the path that you defined while enabling the secret engine (ssh i think in your case)

Comment: @Ren https://stackoverflow.com/users/4857099/ren , please let me know if this did not work else please mark this as answer as it takes effort to investigate this